# Access view model required error message data annotation from Resource file in code - MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to access ErrorMessageString from code to get corresponding message based on user language however i have some difficulties.

In my viewModel i have this:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "UserFirstNameReq")]
    [Display(Name = "UserFirstName", ResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

From English resource file UserFirstNameReq = First name is required. (This will change based on user language selection, for German this will be Vorname ist erforderlich.)

Now i have this code, where i want to access translated message but ErrorMessageString is not accessible. How can i get this value?

```
public static MvcHtmlString ExtendedTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);

        //If input is required in ViewModel, attach required and validation message
        if (metadata.IsRequired)
        {
            string errorAtribute = GetErrorMessage(metadata);

            return InputExtensions.TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(htmlHelper, expression, (string) null, output);
        }

        return InputExtensions.TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(htmlHelper, expression, (string) null, htmlAttributes);
    }

    private static string GetErrorMessage(ModelMetadata metadata)
    {
        string retVal = String.Empty;

        var customTypeDescriptor = new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(metadata.ContainerType).GetTypeDescriptor(metadata.ContainerType);
        if (customTypeDescriptor != null)
        {
            var descriptor = customTypeDescriptor.GetProperties().Find(metadata.PropertyName, true);
            var req = (new List<Attribute>(descriptor.Attributes.OfType<Attribute>())).OfType<RequiredAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

            if (req != null)
            {
                retVal = req.ErrorMessage;

                //Here instead of ErrorMessage i need ErrorMessageString
            }

        }

        return retVal;
     }
```

Here is screenshot of what i need but can't access:

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: did my answer helped you to solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, it's working nicely, ty.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad i could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if using reflections is not an issue, try with

```
retVal =  (string)req.GetType().GetProperty("ErrorMessageString", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(req);
```